# 2 ajax on the same event "onchange" cause conflict

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form with a dropdown list. On change, it calls 2 ajax functions :

```
<select onchange="getLimite(this.value); getPrice(this.value);">
```

Thoses functions call a PHP script which send a SQL query.

Problem : one function works, the other not.

In this way :

```
<select onchange="getLimite(this.value); getPrice(this.value);">
```

Only getPrice(this.value) works.

In this way :

```
<select onchange="getPrice(this.value); getLimite(this.value);">
```

Only getLimite(this.value) works.

Source of one of those functions (for example) :

```
function getPrice(billet) {

   if(billet == 'vide') {
       document.getElementById("blocPrixP").innerHTML = '';
   }
   else {
       var prixBlocP = document.getElementById("blocPrixP");
       prixBlocP.innerHTML = '<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading" title="loading" />';
       creerRequete(); // new XMLHttpRequest();
       var urlPrix = 'prix.php?billet='+billet;
       requete.open('GET', urlPrix, true);
       requete.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(requete.readyState == 4) {
               if(requete.status == 200) {

                   affichePrix();

               }
           }
       };
       requete.send(null);
   }

}
```

prix.php looks like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['billet'])) {
    $billet = $_GET['billet'];
}
else {
    $billet = false;
}


if(false !== $billet) {
    $requete_prix = $bdd->prepare('SELECT nom_billet, prix_billet FROM ce_billet WHERE nom_billet = :nom_billet');
    $requete_prix->execute(array(
        ':nom_billet' => $billet
    ));

    $data = $requete_prix->fetch();
        echo $data['prix_billet'];
}

else {
    echo 'Error'; 
}
```

Edit : the other function

```
    function getLimite(billet_bis) {
       if(billet_bis == 'vide') {
           document.getElementById('blocQuantite').innerHTML = '';
       }
       else {
           var blocQuantite = document.getElementById('blocQuantite');
           blocQuantite.innerHTML = '<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading" title="loading" />';
           creerRequete();
           var url_limite = 'limite.php?billet='+ billet_bis;
           requete.open('GET', url_limite, true);
           requete.onreadystatechange = function()
           {
               if(requete.readyState == 4)
               {
                   if(requete.status == 200)
                   {
                       afficheLimite(); 
                   }
               }
           };
           requete.send(null);
       }
   }
```

limite.php :

```
if(isset($_GET['billet'])) {
    $billet2 = $_GET['billet'];
}
else {
    $billet2 = false;
}

if(false !== $billet2) {
    $requete_limite = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id_billet, nom_billet, limitation_chiffre_billet FROM ce_billet WHERE nom_billet = :nom_du_billet");
    $requete_limite->execute(array(
        ':nom_du_billet' => $billet2
    ));
    $data = $requete_limite->fetch();

    $limite = intval($data['limitation_chiffre_billet']);

    if($limite == '') {
        $liste = NULL;
    }
    else {

        $liste = '<select id="quantite-billet" name="quantite-billet-name" onchange="getQte(document.getElementsByClassName(\'selecttwo\')[0].value);">'; // 
        $liste .= '<option value="vide" id="vide">- - - Choisissez la quantité - - -</option>';

        for($i = 1; $i <= $limite; $i++) {
            $liste .= '<option value="'.$i.'" id="'.$i.'billet">'.$i.'</option>';
        }

        $liste .= '</select>';

    }

    echo $liste;

}

else {
    echo "Erreur";
}
```

Edit 2 : function creerRequete(), function affichePrix(), function afficheLimite()

```
/* creerRequete() */
var requete = null;
function creerRequete() {
    try {
        requete = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (microsoft) {
        try {
            requete = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(autremicrosoft){
            try {
                requete = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(echec) {
                requete = null;
            }
        }
    }
    if(requete == null) {
        alert('Ajax does not work');
    }
}


/* afficheLimite() */
function afficheLimite() {
    var limite = requete.responseText;
    var blocQuantiteb = document.getElementById('blocQuantite');
    blocQuantiteb.innerHTML = limite;

}


/* affichePrix() */

function affichePrix() {
    var prixDuBillet = requete.responseText;
    var prixBloc = $("#blocPrix");
    var totalprice = $("#prixtotal");
    prixBloc.val(parseFloat(prixDuBillet));
    totalprice.val(prixBloc.val() + ' €');

    $('#quantite-billet').on('change', function() {
        var quantite = $("#quantite-billet option:selected").val();    
        totalprice.val((Math.round((prixBloc.val() * parseInt(quantite)) * 100) / 100 ) + ' €'); 
    });

    document.getElementById("blocPrixP").innerHTML = '';

}
```

I don't know how to call the 2 functions separately.

Comment: Can we also see `getLimite()`?

Comment: What do `affichePrix()` and `afficheLimite()` do? That's quite uneasy to guess what you mean by "this function works but not the other". What does "work" mean?

Comment: Those 2 functions get the "requete.responseText" and shows it.

Comment: Shows it how? Could you put the code? (By "not working" you mean that only one of the 2 functions shows something then?)

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Example afficheLimite() :

 function afficheLimite() {
    var limite = requete.responseText;
    var blocQuantiteb = document.getElementById('blocQuantite');
    blocQuantiteb.innerHTML = limite;

}

Comment: Please show the code of these 2 functions. I think I got it, but without seeing the code it would only be a guess. (And I won't spend my next hour asking one question at the time just because you don't show the whole code. :D) You are using `requete` as a global variable or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the two from within a wrapper function, and sending a call to that as your onchange event handler? Like this:

```
<select onchange="getLimiteAndPrice(this.value)">

function getLimiteAndPrice(billet) {
    getLimite(billet);
    getPrice(billet);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't fix anything. You can use multiple function calls in `onchange`. https://jsfiddle.net/HPierce/0gtgy734/1/

Comment: I think my problem is caused by the SQL query. I have two same SQL query at the same time. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

`requete` is a global variable in your code. You use it in both `getLimite()` and `getPrix()` functions. One function overrides the other's value.
Here is what I'd do:

```
function creerRequete() {
    var requete = null;
    try {
        requete = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    //etc.

    // And at the end:
    if(requete == null) {
        alert('Ajax does not work');
    } else {
        return requete;
    }
```

Then in `getPrix()`:

```
function getPrix() {
    [... do your stuff ...]
    var maRequete = creerRequete(); // This is another variable (it exists only inside the function - you can give it another name if you find it easier to understand)

    [... do other stuff ...]
    affichePrix(maRequete);
}
```

Finally:

```
function affichePrix(toujoursMaRequete) {
    // Here you can use requete (you still can give it another name: it exists only inside this function)
    var prixDuBillet = toujoursMaRequete;
}
```

Same with your "Limite" functions.
You could have had a global variable (as you did before) if both function weren't executing at the same time, and changing the variable's value at the same time (or if this specific behavior was wanted).

Comment: mmmmh... I am confused. For example, I can use like this? var blabla = creerRequete(); then affichePrix(blabla); then function affichePrix(blabla) {  var prixDuBillet = requete.responseText or var PrixDuBillet = blabla.responseText ???? }

Comment: I edited my answer with different variable names for "requete" so that you can know what you are using in each function. You might want to read some documentation/tutos about "variable scope in Javascript" to understand all of it.